# Import image sequence in Pencil2D

Tags: animation, linux

I'm using Pencil2D animation software (Pencil2D Git nightly build on Arch Linux). I'm trying to import an image sequence in my timeline, but I always get one blank frame in between 2 images (i.e., if I import a sequence of 10 images, I get 20 frames). Why is that? I've tried to change the fps rate in my timeline, but I always get a double number of frames imported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got the answer in the [pencil2D forum](http://www.pencil2d.org/forums/topic/import-image-sequence/). The alternative is to import the image sequence as a gif.